# Linux core-dump location and abrtd configuration

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, coredump, sigabrt, stack-dump

I'm trying to change the Linux (RHEL6.7) core-dump location to a different directory using the abrtd configuration

(normally it is going to the location core,but according to my research, if you enable abrtd, that will overwrite the default location.)

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/var/tmp/core-%e-%p-%t
```

abrtd.conf dump location looks like this

```
DumpLocation = /data/kdump/abrt/FQDN    (this is a nfs mount)
```

Why my application core-dumps are not going to the /data/kdump/abrt/FQDN
rather /var/tmp location

Am i missing any configuration directive ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which linux you're using, but you need to change the `core_pattern` so that it includes a pipe with the path to `abrt` binary, like so:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp /var/spool/abrt %s %c %p %u %g %t %h %e 636f726500
```

That way the system knows that the core dump is to be piped through to abrt. The value was taken from here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61536

edit: there's also a nice explenation here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192716/how-to-set-the-core-dump-file-location-and-name

Comment: sorry, i'm using RHEL 6.7 and according to the documentation, if you install abrt-addon-ccpp, that will overwrite the configuration . But in my case that doesn't work.

Comment: @Tharanga Abeyseela did you try the link I added on edit? Maybe you have somewhere in your system an override on the core_pattern which sets it to /var/tmp on startup

Comment: I'm guessing that reinstalling or setting the core_pattern value manually doesn't work either?